# How to preserve the value of a uitextfield during a scroll

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was having troubles using the dequeue mechanism in my tableview, i have a custom cell with a uiTextField.
When a put some value on it and do a scroll, the value of the TextField goes to another cell.
Anybody can help me on it ?
Thanks guys.
Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyPedidoItemCell";

  PedidoItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  // Configure the cell...
  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[PedidoItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  Produto *produto = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  cell.lblNome.text   = produto.nome;
  cell.lblCodigo.text = produto.codigo;
  cell.lblFuncao.text = produto.funcao;
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: I would blame your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. But you did not post any code so who knows.

Comment: When a user enters something into the textfield in one of your custom cells are you storing that text anywhere?

Comment: No i don't store it anywhere.

Comment: Can you post the definitions of PedidoItemCell and Produto? Which UITextField has the wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

**The code you showed is using CoreData to load data for cell, but you mentioned that you don't store the data anywhere.**

I suspect that the you are getting object with no data from your `fetchedResultsController` because you did not store any data.

So quite possibly the `produto` is nil and you are not setting any values on cell.

Eventually the cell you updated manually gets reused and you see the text again.

You need to first store the data that you typed into the UITextField before you can retrieve it from core data.

Comment: The amount of cells can be different. Because of that i can't use the statics cells. The data comes from a table.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` it may return a cell that has scrolled out of view but still contains data in the UITextField. If you don't clear the content of the UITextField or set it to the proper value for the row, you may see unwanted data.